# Ajax Bootstrap Popover: Object #<Object> has no method 'popover'

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to build an Ajax Bootstrap Popover to display a page that contains a rating star system.

The javascript here work nice the first time.
Then I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'popover'

I'm not really good in jQuery, but I guess it seems to be due to the ajax call, but I can't find where the problem is.

```
$(".myRate")
        .popover({
            offset: 10,
            trigger: 'manual',
            animate: false,
            html: true,
            placement: 'top',
            template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function()  {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

        });
$('.myRate').mouseenter(popoverDisplay);

popoverDisplay = function() {
var el = $(this);
var _data = el.attr('alt');
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'notes.php',
     data: _data,
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data) {
        el.attr('data-content', data);
        el.popover('show');
     }
  });
}
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong...
Any idea ?

**EDIT:**

After searching, it seems that, it's the loaded pages which causes this error.

Exactly this part:

It seems that loading jquery-1.7.2.js make the bug because if I remove it, the error disapear. Problem: I can't delete it because without it jRating doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: One error I can see is that you're referencing `popoverDisplay` before you define it. Since `popoverDisplay` is not a hoisted function, this will error. This appears an unrelated issue to the one you mention, however.

Comment: Yeah, I just moved, the popoverDisplay function for this post ^^'

Comment: Which line throws the error - presumably `el.popover('show')`? This can mean only one of two things, unlikely though they might seem given you say the rest of the code is working: 1) `el` is not a jQuery object; 2) `popover()` is not a properly defined jQuery plugin (i.e. method)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this problem after running the rails twitter bootstrap generator, then switching to bootstrap-sass.

It was caused by a filename collision because boostrap-sass references bootstrap.js instead of twitter/bootstrap, which clashes with the generated file.

Just rename the generated app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee to something else, eg app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap_and_overrides.js.coffee, and you're good to go.

Comment: Same problem with twitter bootstrap front end colliding with rails admin back end. Fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem because i was trying to use the jQuery from bootstrap while also importing jQuery from googleapis
(like it says in http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)
if you're using bootstrap, you'll have jquery

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem .
you might be loading jquery AFTER loading bootstrap.js . for some reason the sequence is important

```
</footer>
<script src="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."assets/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ;?>"></script>   
<script src="<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" ;?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    create_project_form=$('form#create_project_form');
    $('button#create_project_button').popover({title:'New Project',content:create_project_form});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

loading jquery before bootstrap did the job for me . hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was loading jQuery.js twice... Narf...

Answer (score 0):

You can either use boostrap.js or (bootstrap-popover.js and bootstrap-tooltip.js)

But not both because if you use both. You get `Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'popover'`

Comment: I finaly ended with an other style of display so I don't need this anymore but didn't find a way to fix it :/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using `rails`, so it might come that `assets/vendor/jquery` is loaded after `assets/vendor/bootstrap`, because the load order is alphabetical. So you might rename the `bootstrap` file to fit the right loading order. I experienced that problem and it did the trick